# Animation stuck at the beginning unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok so I have a few animations on my character in unity, but when I hit play, in the Animator tab I see that the blue bar remains at the beginning. Although, if (while I am still in playmode) I uncheck the boxes for my boolean variables in animator, it works correctly. This is my code, please help:

````
    {
        foreach(AnimatorControllerParameter parameter in shaggyAnim.parameters)
        {
            shaggyAnim.SetBool (parameter.name, false);//stops the other animations
            shaggyAnim.SetBool(anim, true);//plays the wanted animation
            //for each animation I declared a bool variable inside unity animator

        }

    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the Default State? You don't need to check all the animation parameters at the beginning. Just set the animation which you want as default state and unity will play that animation only at the beginning. Just make sure all other parameters in transition are false.